# Google Play License Service: Assertions about the userId field?

Tags: android, google-play

According to its reference implementation, we are to assume that the **Google Play Licensing** Serv{ice,er}, in the [**userId** field of its response](http://code.google.com/p/marketlicensing/source/browse/library/src/com/android/vending/licensing/ResponseData.java), returns an [// **Application-specific user identifier**.](http://code.google.com/p/marketlicensing/source/browse/library/src/com/android/vending/licensing/LicenseValidator.java#155) On the other hand, the [LVL reference](http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/licensing-reference.html) makes no such commitment.

In practice, the returned value appears to be lengthy binary data, possibly even starting with (at least) a `0x00` byte, Base64 encoded.

One should assume from the comment that this field's value represents the customer's ID, obfuscated but still **unique on a per-app basis**, such that the customer can be identified using this value, while on the other hand not being suitable for figuring out whether it's the same customer as with another app one has potentially published.

However, if one were to rely on this assumption for business, it should be **officially confirmed**, and I can't find such a confirmation. Also, a **maximum length** assertion would be rather helpful, but I have not found one so far.

Has anybody found additional information on this or is willing to share their experience? I'd appreciate this very much.

**Update:** Can anybody confirm that those IDs consist of 24 x 8 bit binary data, padded with a leading (25th) `0x00` byte?

Comment: Some investigation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40894999/whats-in-signeddata-parameter-of-ilicenseresultlistener-verifylicense/40901602#40901602