# What's in signedData parameter of ILicenseResultListener.verifyLicense?

Tags: android, google-play

Google Play on Android has a service for license checks, `com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService`. It supports a callback interface, `ILicenseResultListener`. It has a method `verifyLicense` with three parameters. For a paid app that's been downloaded from Google Play, what comes in the second one, `signedData`, please?

And [this](http://rathertech.blogspot.com/2016/12/google-play-fraud.html) is why I'm wondering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in android-sdk-windows\extras\google\market_licensing\library\src\com\google\android\vending\licensing\ResponseData.java, in the parse() method.

The signedData string is a sequence of 6 fields, separated by |, optionally followed by colon and a &-separated name=value collection (like a query string). For example:

```
0|17|com.acme.myapp|1|AAAAABBBBCCCCDDDDEEEEFFFFGGGGHHHHH==|1480563297411:GR=10&VT=1480570457760&GT=1481088857760
```

This one comes from a paid app.

The 6 fields in the first section are:

- Response code (int) - presumably the same as the `verifyLicense`'s first parameter
- Nonce (int) - comes straight from the `checkLicense` call
- Package name
- Version code
- User ID, with a comment "Application-specific user identifier"
- Timestamp (long) - not sure of what. Definitely not purchase; repeat runs return a different, later value. Probably that of license check itself.

UserID seems to be a Base64-encoded string. Which user does it identify, and how? The license holder, one presumes; but how? Decoding gives a byte array, 25 bytes long.

For a sideloaded app, the basic fields is all there is. For a store bought app, there's extra data. The meaning of extra data fields can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/licensing-reference.html). Specifically, with a freshly bought app, the following extra fields come:

- GR - max retry count
- VT - license validity timestamp; specifies when the license needs to be rechecked
- GT - grace period timestamp

Regarding UserID, I did some tests. I have three cases:

- Package A, side-loaded
- Package A, downloaded for a fee from Play
- Package B, downloaded for free from Play (by the same user)

In all three cases, the first 5 bytes of the decoded UserID have the same value 00D94E1D03, the rest don't. So neither the package unique part nor the user unique part can be easily identified in the UserID. Notably, the remainder is 20 bytes long - could be an MD5 hash. The UserID definitely isn't a string in any sensible encoding, and it doesn't look like a structure with binary integers, either. The seemingly random bit pattern points at either a hash, or a cyphertext. The latter is unlikely.

Comment: Thank you for sharing and leaving a comment on [Google Play License Service: Assertions about the userId field?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14578627/1856738). Still, no assertion from Google about the length -- doesn't make professional work with Android easier.

Comment: For additional information, I have an app that I made free, and the userId stayed the same. However, this check was with a debug release side-loaded (before and after made free) where the version number matched the latest version on Google Play.

Answer (score 1):

Further to the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40901602/444761), I have some different (contradicting) findings regarding the `userId`.

The `userId` is the same for the same user-app combination regardless whether the app was sideloaded or installed from Google Play Store or whether it is Debug or Release build. The only important point here is that the version code for that app has already been uploaded (perhaps also needs to Published to some track, not sure) to the Google Play Store, because it needs to know about the version before giving license responses.

Furthermore, if the app is made free, then the `userId` still does not change. The main difference in the response is that now it will give `Long.MAX_VALUE` for the `VT` (Validity Timestamp). This is true for both user who purchased the app (before it was free) and users who installed the app (after it was made free).